# How to insert or embed sample code to my html page's with the right color?

Tags: html, embed

example is stackoverflow's sample code area, where you see the code being presented,

I tried using the the  and  tags, but it only display a plain black text,

I want to look like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FX1Th.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfBbU.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse each and every word being typed. Words that you see  coloured are nothing but 'reserved words'.
Simply use a rich text-editor like [tinymce](https://www.tinymce.com/). Or you need to write a custom parser for the same.